# Form Validation

Tags: javascript, angular

I am just getting started in Angular 2 and I'm trying to figure out how to validate a form so that it doesn't allow anything less than $.01 to be entered. I have tried a few different things, but so far, it will still allow the submit button to be pressed. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Check this link out. Should provide you with guidance: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validation

Comment: Please try to add what did you tried and their results ?

Comment: One of the things that I tried was to use a different regex in the form, but that didn't really work out at all. It would still allow the button to be pressed. I also tried to use the ngModel Object, but I am sure that I wasn't using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is binding the 0.01 input with $scope.balance, binding the save button with $scope.save.
For example your template is like the following:

```
<div>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Balance</label>
    <input ng-model="balance" type="number" required>
  </md-input-container>
  <div style="color:red">{{error}}</div>
  <md-button ng-click="answer()>Save</md-button>
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.balance = 0;
$scope.save = function() {
  if ($scope.balance < 0.01) {
    $scope.error = "Please enter some value that is no less than 0.01";
    return; // any invalidate number will not be saved.
  }
  // do your other save operation
}
```

By doing this, you have flexibility to do other validations and give your own error message to users.

Comment: Your answer is for AngularJS (as in version 1.x), the question asks for Angular (version 2 and above). There is no `$scope` in "Angular 2" anymore.

Comment: Oh, yes. My solution is only for AngularJS.